# Android: unable to show correct hindi words

Tags: android, hindi

I am working in android. I am designing an application which shows Hindi words in text view.

I am using this code.

```
        String str="दिव्या";
        TextView txtview_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewmyView);

        final Typeface customF = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Hindi-SARAL1.TTF");

       txtview_name.setTypeface(customF);

       txtview_name.setText(str);
```

I used font in my resourses like **DroidHindi.ttf, DroidSansFallback.ttf** etc. this is showing some words correctly like as **समर**, राजा etc , but this does not show correctly words like as **दिव्या** So please suggest me what .ttf i should use so each word of Hindi show correctly.

Comment: Though the thread is 2 years old, maybe [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188269/android-2-x-devanagari-unicode-issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188269/android-2-x-devanagari-unicode-issue) is same as this thread.

Answer (score 1):

@Pushpendra I was having same problem with my testing device (HTC phone).
But i tried same app on samsung android phone it works properly on it. 
So i think you should try your app on different device
May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .ttf file, use .otf file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Unicode instead of direct value...

```
String str="&# 2367;&# 2342;&# 2357;&# 2381;&# 2351;&# 2366;";
```

continious no gap.

```
TextView txtview_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewmyView);

final Typeface customF = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Hindi-SARAL1.TTF");

txtview_name.setText(Html.fromHtml(""+str));
txtview_name.setTypeface(customF);
```

and you can also convert world to unicode via this site...http://mylanguages.org/converter.php
but in case of दि use 1st unicode of इ  then 2nd  द ..b/c till android 4.0 not support proper Hindi unicode..`&# 2342;` is unicode of द.