# Android - Hindi Conjuncts Support?

Tags: android, fonts, hindi

I do understand that Android device still doesn't support complex hindi conjuncts drawing, though we set the textView typeface to a commonly used hindi font (mangal.ttf or DroidHindi.ttf).

One of the Ex:

1st     2nd     Conjunct

प्        र     =  प्र

"प्र" is been shown as...प् र    { list of frequently used conjuncts - [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Hindi/Consonant_combinations))

What I would be interested to know is - Though android devices(I am using Galaxy-SII, os2.3) doesn't support it yet, is there a workaround for this?

Similar questions (but no workaround yet):

1. [Android: unable to show correct hindi words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329510/android-unable-to-show-correct-hindi-words)
2. [How can i show HIndi text in Android Tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789827/how-can-i-show-hindi-text-in-android-tablet)

For the question-2:  @Sahaja does mention that android device doesn't support hindi complex conjuncts drawing. So does it mean that we won't be able to do anything in this regard until android adds the support for it or can we have a feasible workaround?

One workaround, which I can think of:

1. Convert the whole hindi database into a custom non-unicode format & use a non-unicode font (like kiran.ttf - [link](http://www.kiranfont.com/kf/)) to display it. This sounds like too much of effort, not sure if this is a feasible solution (not tried it yet - kept as last option) or something else would also work?

Please let me know, your thoughts on the same.

**(Note: This problem has nothing to do with what custom hindi font I use or is it ttf or otf.)**

Thanks,
Shibbs

Comment: yep! Infact I did tried over 20-30 custom hindi fonts, before realizing the font used is not an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been through the same problem but unfortunately didn't find any solution. I agree that some of the text won't appear properly i.e. some of it may appear misplaced characters. If you try running it on device that is 3.0 or above (I am unsure of below 3.0), then you should be able to see it properly. Or try choosing en emulator with higher which has more than 4.0.[image]