# Android 2.x devanagari unicode issue

Tags: java, android, unicode

I am trying to support for devanagari font for android 2.x (even though android 2.x is not capable of rendering the devanagari font) using following code. The code is working fine except having some issues with 'raswa' and 'dirga'. Is it possible to obtain the correct devanagari representation in android 2.x ?

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mangal.ttf");
TextView txtviewword=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWord);
txtviewword.setTypeface(typeface);
```

This is incorrect representation(from android 2.3):

[image]

This should have been rather like this(from android 4.4):

[image]

Comment: u mean same code is represented in 2 device differently?

Comment: yes. partly due to the reason that android 2.x are not capable of rendering devanagari font correctly.

Comment: i think its from famework...any alternative ttf?

Comment: switching ttf doesn't work either.

Comment: Complex layout rendering needs to be supported by text layout engine: from what I know, you have either provide your own from who-knows-where, or give up.

Comment: @KarolS Thank you for you information. I will try to accomplish myself then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing my situation over the problem, I found that swapping the position of 'raswa' with the alphabet ('akshar') itself would solve the problem for gingerbread. So, I swapped the position of 'raswa' and alphabet. So, this provided the problem workaround.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
   char[] array = content[1].toCharArray();   /*content[1] is a string containing the original version */
   for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        char c = array[i];
        int code = (int) c;
        if (code == 2367){    //2367 is int value for 'raswa'
            char temp = array[i-1];
            array[i-1]=c;
            array[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    String str = String.copyValueOf(array); /*This string contains the swapped version(symantically its wrong, though. It's works as my solution.)*/
    Log.d("DetailActivity", "from gingerbread");
    Log.d("DetailActivity", str);
    if(!content[1].equals(null))txtviewdevanagari.setText(str);
}else{
    Log.d("DetailActivity", "from ICS+");
    if(!content[1].equals(null))txtviewdevanagari.setText(content[1]);
}
```